# Does the distribution of a randomly baised coin approach a fair coin distribtion if the sample size is relatively large?

Tags: probability

I appolgize if the answer is trivial, as I wanted to confirm my suspicions about the question, and that the answer is indeed trival.

Given:

- The bias, $B$, of an unfair coin is defined as ${B∈ℝ:0≤B≤1}$, where $B = P(Heads)$
- Likewise, $P(Tails) = 1-P(Heads) = 1-P(B)$
- The possible values of $B$ are evenly distrubuted within $(0,1)$
- Bias $B$<sub>i</sub> is the bias on the ith coin flip, with  $B$<sub>i+1</sub> being determined prior to the $i+1$th coin flip. The particular values of these variables are not known.
- $n$ is the total number of coin flips

If $n$ is relatively large, I would think that the distribution of every coin flip would approach that of a fair coin, as the expected vaule for the trend of a particular bias $B$<sub>i</sub> would be one flip. So, I would assume all the biases would eventually "cancel" each other out, causing the disturbtion to apporach that of a fair coin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be saying each coin $i$ has a probability of heads of $B_i$ where the different $B_i$s are uniformly and independently distributed on $[0,1]$

In that case, by symmetry, the probability that a particular coin shows heads is $\frac12$.

So the law of large numbers says that the proportion showing heads $X_n$ of a sample size $n$ converges in probability and almost surely to $\frac12$ as the sample size increases.  $\mathbb E[X]=\frac12$ and $\text{Var}(X_n)=\frac1{4\sqrt{n}}$, and the central limit theorem shows $\sqrt{n}(X_n -\frac12)$ converges in distribution to the normal distribution $\mathcal N(0,\frac14)$

Answer (score 1):

In fact, your coin is indistinguishable from a fair coin.

The probability that the $i$th toss is heads equals the probability that a uniform random number $X_i\in(0,1)$ is $<B_i$. With $X_i$ and $B_i$ independent, it follows by symmetry that this probability is $\frac12$. (And of course different tosses are independent provided the $B_i$ are also independent, which you probably intend to have).

Comment: Thank you. I had suspicion that, almost paradoxily, the bias doesn't even exist. But, what you are saying is that given two coins, one that is fair and the other that is baised as I describe, could not be distinguished between each other within some margin if fliped together.

Comment: @QHZ - The issue is that the bias is random, and equally likely to be towards heads as towards tails, so for a single flip you cannot distinguish between this randomly biased coin and a fair coin.  Then for the next flip you move on to a differently biased coin.  The answers would be different if you flipped the same biased coin repeatedly